# RxJava2 buffer with debounce

Tags: java, rx-java2

I want to buffer elements and emit them as collection when there is no new element for x amount of time. how to do that?

For example given input

```
INPUT    TIME
1        0  
2        0
3        100
4        150
5        400
6        450
7        800
```

If my x=200 I want to emit `{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7}`

What I tried is simple `buffer()` with time, but it doesn't offer debounce. I also tried `throttleFirst()` on source and `flatMap()` it with `buffer().take(1)` on source inside `flatMap`, it works similarly but not exactly as desired.

Comment: Something like debounce with reducing function as parameter would be great

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need `publish` as you need the same source to control the buffering behavior through a debounce:

```java
static <T> ObservableTransformer<T, List<T>> bufferDebounce(
        long time, TimeUnit unit, Scheduler scheduler) {
    return o ->
        o.publish(v -> 
            v.buffer(v.debounce(time, unit, scheduler)
                .takeUntil(v.ignoreElements().toObservable())
            )
        );
}

@Test
public void test() {
    PublishSubject<Integer> ps = PublishSubject.create();

    TestScheduler sch = new TestScheduler();

    ps.compose(bufferDebounce(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, sch))
    .subscribe(
            v -> System.out.println(sch.now(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)+ ": " + v),
            Throwable::printStackTrace,
            () -> System.out.println("Done"));

    ps.onNext(1);
    ps.onNext(2);

    sch.advanceTimeTo(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    ps.onNext(3);

    sch.advanceTimeTo(150, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    ps.onNext(4);

    sch.advanceTimeTo(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    ps.onNext(5);

    sch.advanceTimeTo(450, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    ps.onNext(6);

    sch.advanceTimeTo(800, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    ps.onNext(7);
    ps.onComplete();

    sch.advanceTimeTo(850, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

The `takeUntil` is there to prevent the completion of `o` to trigger an empty buffer.

Comment: Thanks! It works as expected. What I thought, is you can also store results as List outside of stream and then `clear()`, `add()` items in appropriate places. Something like debouncing on android TextView, which internally stores entire String